# Simple jQuery function not picking up click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am having a go at my very first jQuery function. What needs to happen is that a form will be assigned to the function. When a user clicks on the submit button it needs to first do validation on each :input field within the the function.

I am assigning a form as the selector for my function:

```
  $("form[name='form_name']").validator();
```

This then gets passed into the function and is assigned to a function property called "selected_form". Within my jQuery function I have another function which needs to wait for the submit button to be clicked, and after that it needs to iterate through all of the :input form elements and handle simple validation.

The issue now is:

a) Within my jQuery function I am making a call to `return validate();` Validate then checks to see whether the button as clicked. I suspect that because the function is run and there was no button clicked, it continues and basically returns the validate() function back as false without doing any checks. I assume I will need to customize this to almost wait until the button is pressed, but I really have no idea how to do that.

b) `$(selected_form+" :input").each(function() { ... }` does not work as it appears to not be able to use that as a selected. I need to iterate through the "selected_form" property and select only the :input fields. Any assistance?

c) If you have any other suggestions or best practices for me regarding building a proper jQuery function please assist, this is my first attempt and I would rather learn the best practices now as appose to following my own ideas.

```
 (function($) {
$.fn.validator = function(user_options) {

    var default_options = {
        exclusions: false,
        rules: false,
        submit_btn_name: 'event_form_submit'
    };

    var selected_form = this;
    var selected_element = false;
    var element_type = false;

    var options = $.extend(default_options,user_options);

    function validate() {

        // Run only if form has been submitted: (this does not appear to work now, the form gets submitted without the return false;
        $("input[type='"+options.submit_name+"']").click(function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();

            // The selector here appears to be wrong?
            $(selected_form+" :input").each(function() {

                // Individual element validation will happen here, for now I am just looking to log the element types :)

                selected_element = this;
                console.log(get_element_type());

            });
            return false;
        });    
        return false;
    };

    function get_element_type() {
        return element_type = element.type;
    }

    return validate();

}
})(jQuery);

 // Run the validator: 
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("form[name='tepg_form_processor']").validator(); 
 });
```

Comment: When you are assigning the click, you use a different name `options.submit_name` than is declared in the object `submit_btn_name`. Also the selector for an input should not have a colon: `$(selected_form + ' input')`

Comment: would you mind posting a jsfiddle including the html?

Comment: @jalynn2, excellent observation, thank you for helping with that. I tried removing the colon but no luck, I am getting a " Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]input" in console.

Comment: `selected_form` is a DOM element not a string, so try ` $(selected_form).find(input)...`

Comment: @Evan = http://jsfiddle.net/RbHPL/ (i hope this helps)

Comment: I can recommend using the forms `submit` event rather than a buttons `click` event.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, I changed it according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jalynn2 and others have mentioned, my selector was incorrect. Fixed and working :)